# Unable to install Ubuntu Server 14.04 in HP Proliant dl580 G7

Tags: 14.04

Has anyone installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 in an HP Proliant dl580 G7 server?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. At the moment, this question isn't really a good fit for our QA format, and is difficult to answer. To improve it, describe what you have tried, list any error messages, or describe what doesn't work, and ask a specific question. (Think of this as "question and answer wikipedia" rather than a forum.)

Answer (score 2):

That computer is certified with Ubuntu Server 12.04.1LTS 64bit: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201401-14573/

Because of that and the limited amount of information you provide, I'll just say "Yes – you can install Ubuntu 14.04LTS Server on that machine" and there should be little or no exceptions to the normal procedure.

If you do have specific issues with Ubuntu on this computer, then you should clarify exactly what those are at the Ubuntu Certified feedback page: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+addquestion?field.title=Feedback%20on%20the%20HP%20ProLiant%20DL580%20G7